# Ajax success function is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost/api/v1/courses?access_token=[MY-ACCESS-TOKEN]',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert("success " + data);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

I am trying to access this API. I am able to see a response in Firebug but it is not firing the `success` function of `$.ajax`. How can I solve this one?

Comment: Does your console states anything?

Comment: jsonp requires a callback : http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: PLease try to load your URL in browser then check.

Comment: The `jsonp` argument is to specify the callback parameter name - it's not supposed to be `true` or `false`.  Leave it off unless your API requires a callback argument named something different than `callback=xxxx`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the option `jsonp: false`. The [`jsonp` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) tells jQuery what **name** to give the JSONP callback function. So you're telling jQuery to use `"false"` as the callback function name. Fortunately, jQuery *doesn't* actually use that name (I just [tried it](http://jsbin.com/eSUcAYe/1) — if it did, the JSONP coming back would fail), but putting that option there effectively turns off the `dataType: "jsonp"` you specified earlier, making jQuery try an actual ajax (non-JSONP) request, which fails.

Remove the `jsonp` option entirely to let jQuery do a JSONP request and to allow it to control the callback name.